# VBS script find and delete file

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to find a specific file on computer and delete it.

This is my code:

```
Const DeleteReadOnly = True 

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set oWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
sDir = oWshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%temp%\dir.txt") 
sFileName = "\date.vbs" 

If oFSO.FileExists(sDir) Then oFSO.DeleteFile(sDir) 

For Each oDrive In oFSO.Drives 
if oDrive.DriveType = 2 Then Search oDrive.DriveLetter 
Next 

Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sDir, 1) 
aNames = Split(oFile.ReadAll, VbCrLf) 
oFile.Close 
For Each sName In aNames 
If InStr(1, sName, sFileName, 1) > 0 Then WScript.Echo sName 
Next 

dim filesys 
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
filesys.CreateTextFile "\date.vbs", True 
If filesys.FileExists("\date.vbs") Then 
filesys.DeleteFile "\date.vbs" 
Wscript.Echo("File deleted") 
End If 


Sub Search(sDrive) 
WScript.Echo "Scanning drive " & sDrive & ":" 
oWshShell.Run "cmd /c dir /s /b " & sDrive & ":\" & sName & " >>" & sDir, 0, True 
End Sub
```

The code is working only partially. When the file "date.vbs" is in root folder (C:\date.vbs) then it is deleted but when it is in folder (C:\backup\date.vbs) then it will not be deleted. Do you know which code changes I should make to be able to delete file even when it is not in root but anywhere in computer?

Thank you! V.

UPDATE:

The code is pretty much working right now. I just have a final problem of deleting the file. I am able to change the attributes from Read-only to normal but still i get the error of access denied.

This is my code:

```
Const DeleteReadOnly = True 
Dim oFSO, oDrive, sFileName, ws, WshS, fso, usrProfile, oFolder, skypefolder

Set oFSO   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
sFileName  = "Skype.exe"

Set WshS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
usrProfile = WshS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")
skypefolder = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\"

For Each oDrive In oFSO.Drives 
  If oDrive.DriveType = 2 Then Recurse oFSO.GetFolder(skypefolder)
Next 

Sub Recurse(oFolder)
  Set oFile   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
  Dim oSubFolder, oFile

  If IsAccessible(oFolder) Then
    For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
     Recurse oSubFolder
    Next 
    WScript.Echo oFolder.Path

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
      If oFile.Name = sFileName And oFile.Attributes And 1 Then
        oFile.Attributes = 0
        oFile.Delete True

      End If
      Next 
  End If
End Sub

Function IsAccessible(oFolder)
  On Error Resume Next
  IsAccessible = oFolder.SubFolders.Count >= 0
End Function
```

Thank you for help!

Code I use to run the script as ADMIN. After this it started to show the MessageBoxes. Before it was running in a console.

```
If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevated") = False Then

    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" &     WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevated", "", "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
Else

    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    oShell.CurrentDirectory =     CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
    'WScript.Echo("Now running with elevated permissions")

End If
```

So I believe there is something wrong in this code.

Comment: On a general note: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is much too complicated. Use a simple recursive function:

```
Option Explicit

Const DeleteReadOnly = True 
Dim oFSO, oDrive, sFileName

Set oFSO   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
sFileName  = "date.vbs"

For Each oDrive In oFSO.Drives 
  If oDrive.DriveType = 2 Then Recurse oDrive.RootFolder
Next 

Sub Recurse(oFolder)
  Dim oSubFolder, oFile

  If IsAccessible(oFolder) Then
    For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
     Recurse oSubFolder
    Next 

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
      If oFile.Name = sFileName Then
        'oFile.Delete ' or whatever
      End If
    Next 
  End If
End Sub

Function IsAccessible(oFolder)
  On Error Resume Next
  IsAccessible = oFolder.SubFolders.Count >= 0
End Function
```

To achieve case-insensitive file name comparison, you could use

```
If StrComp(oFile.Name, sFileName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
```

Comment: thank you, i sort of liked the scanning part, becausei knew that something is going on. How can I then implement the deleting? no matter which syntax i try it does not work . I tried oFile.Delete(sFileName) I used the name of the file as filename and it still returns error

Comment: @Vojtech `oFile.Delete` should work well. If you want to see what's going on, add `WScript.Echo oFolder.Path` right before the `IsAccessible()` check. Note that you must run the script on the command line with `cscript.exe yourscript.vbs`, otherwise (i.e. if you start it via doubleclick) it will generate one MessageBox for each folder.

Answer (score 3):

As an exercise: You can also use the WMI Service to find certain files. You don't have to go through all folders, you just query the file on any drive, on any folder:

```
Function find_file(filename)

    Dim objWMIService, colItems, objItem, strComputer
    strComputer = "."

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE FileName='" & filename & "'",,48)

    For Each objItem in colItems
        msgbox "Found " & objItem.Name & " in " objItem.Path
    Next

End Function
```

Note: It can take long before the function has returned its results.

Comment: +1, very nice. Care to comare the two solutions for performance? :)

Comment: The WMI solution took 0.4 seconds, the recursive search took 12 seconds. Performance was only measured on the C: drive.

Comment: Interesting. I figured the WMI would be faster, but *that* difference is astonishing. Did you run them multiple times to compensate for the effect of Windows file system caching?

Comment: @AutomatedChaos Thank you for the answer. Where exactly I am suppose to to insert the name of the file I am looking for? I tried some alternatives but I either got an error or the script just ran and never returned anything. I left it running for several minutes and nothing happened.

Comment: Yes, I tried it multiple times and the results were the same within a 10% deviation.
@Vojtech; it will help if you use the query `"SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Drive='c:' AND FileName='" & filename & "'"` if you first test it. It will only search your C: drive. If that works, you can create a more generic query over multiple drives. Filename can only be the real filename without extension, but I think you can figure out how to implement the extension in the query.
To Test: create a testfile.txt anywhere on your C:\ and Call the function as: `call find_files("testfile")`

Comment: @AutomatedChaos yeah, it works perfect. Now I am trying to figure out the extension and adding another drive to it with extending the WHERE statement with AND but that doesnt do the job. But I think I will figure it out somehow, same goes for the extensions. Tried it like select *.txt which gives error and filename & "'.txt" which also gives an error. But my question is how to look in other drive folders because when I try c:\users it doesnt like the \

Comment: @Vojtech you have to use a double \\ because it is seen as an escape character in the query. You can take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394594(v=vs.85).aspx) for some other hints on creating your queries, and this [article about the WMI query language](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1509) can help you even more if you want to make more extensive queries.