# 'Step Into' is suddenly not working in WCF Dataservice

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Every thing was fine a few weeks ago, i Could step into the Dataservice without any problem , but all of sudden it has stopped.i have changed nothing but it does not work. i searched a lot  anf found that in Properties of Solution, if i select Multiple Startup Project and the select DataService Project and UserInterface Project and then select their Action to Start, i could setp into the Data Service , and it worked for a few days , but that doesn't work neither.

there is nothing special about stepping into the DataService as I searched Except that DataService and UserInterface Project should be in the same Solution ( which are) and the set the breakpoint ( which i set)

this is the end point I used

```
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:63407/CableService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICableService" contract="CableServiceReference.ICableService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_ICableService" />
```

I found these
['Step Into' is suddenly not working in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801385/step-into-is-suddenly-not-working-in-visual-studio#)  and 
http://briannoyesblogwp.azurewebsites.net/2008/05/10/the-evil-suo-file-fighting-and-winning-with-visual-studio/

but that those didn't work out, i don't know what should i do to resolve the problem .

I started to work with project on another Computer, on that computer it is possible to step into the DataService , but it is possible to step into the DataService from my PC

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging the Data Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23179214/debugging-the-data-services)

Comment: what do u mean by duplicate of Debugging the Data Services? The same program fines on the other pc without problem but on my mine. i use TFS so i just connect to one source from any pc .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**!!! I uninstalled the VS2010 and removed all the folders remained on Program Files and Application Data, and the reinstalled it. the problem solved . now i can step into Dataservice , either on remote computer or localhost