# XUnit tests output in Output Window but not in Test Explorer and cannot be debugged

Tags: visual-studio, xunit

I have an XUnit test which is failing with a nullreference exception, probably there's some property on one of the objects that I need to give a value for but haven't. That would be easy to figure out, except attempting to debug tests isn't working. If I try to debug it with the little icon between [Fact] and the test declaration, it tells me: `Test run finished in 3.4 ms. 0 Total tests - 0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped` and none of the breakpoints get hit. If I look at the test in at Test Explorer, it has the Not Run icon. The way I know it's a nullreference exception is by going to the output window, `Show output from Tests`, and looking there. I have the `xunit.runner.visualstudio` nuget package installed in my test package. Any ideas?

Comment: NullReference exception, as any other exception, contains a line number where exception were thrown.

Comment: yeah, the nullreference itself isn't so much what I'm concerned about, the real problem is why isn't the test run connected to the test explorer?

Comment: +1 for mentioning `xunit.runner.visualstudio`. Have you tried the steps mentioned on this SO response? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10908685/3298119